# gnuplot install failure - recipe for target 'qtgnuplot_fr.qm' failed

Tags: gnuplot

When installing gnuplot 5.0.0 (and 5.0.7, too),using ./configure && make,

```
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/lrelease qtterminal/po/qtgnuplot_fr.ts -qm qtgnuplot_fr.qm
/bin/bash: /usr/lib/qt5/bin/lrelease: No such file or directory
Makefile:1335: recipe for target 'qtgnuplot_fr.qm' failed
make[4]: *** [qtgnuplot_fr.qm] Error 127
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/seolhwa/Downloads/gnuplot-5.0.7/src'
Makefile:1027: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/seolhwa/Downloads/gnuplot-5.0.7/src'
Makefile:644: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/seolhwa/Downloads/gnuplot-5.0.7/src'
Makefile:419: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/seolhwa/Downloads/gnuplot-5.0.7'
Makefile:357: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

At first, I installed gnuplot using 
    apt install gnuplot
the latest version was installed. But it missed pdfcairo. So I installed two necessary dev files and other recommended dev files (for the possible use of qt terminal). Then I moved to gnuplot folder and configure && make. The result is above.
What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The Qt translation support is in a separate package qttools5 (precise name depends on your linux distro).  If you are going to the trouble of installing from source, why use gnuplot 5.0 rather than current 5.2?

Comment: Maybe unclear in my post, I couldn't use pdfcairo with 5.2. Before, a similar error that occurred with the newest gnuplot at that time (5.x) was cleared with installing a lower version. That's why I lowered the version after the first failure. Now with version 4.6, pdfcairo works fine...

Comment: I don't see anything in the output you show that involves pdfcairo.  The errors shown are caused by not having the "lrelease" program that is provided by the qttools package.

Comment: I see. Still, I don't understand why the error only with qt also prevented pdfcairo from being installed. Also, wonder why installing gnuplot (not from source) didn't automatically load pdfcairo and qt terminals..